# uwsgitop Doesn't Show Processes

Tags: python, uwsgi

Today I upgraded uwsgi and uwsgitop using pip and running in a vitrualenv on Ubuntu. After the upgrade uwsgitop stop reporting on the 4 processes I had running.

I'm running uwsgi 2.0.13.1 with the following config:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.myapp.socket
pythonpath = /srv/myapp
processes = 4
harakiri = 2
max-requests = 2000
callable = app
stats = /tmp/uwsgi.myapp.statsock
# Turn this off for production
catch-exceptions = true
```

When I run a check on the processes I can see that there are 5 processes running. 17279, the master and the 4 other uwsgi processes spawned by it.

```
(myapp-flask)admin@myapp:~$ ps ax | grep wsgi
17279 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp.log
17284 ?        S      0:01 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp.log
17285 ?        S      0:01 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp.log
17286 ?        S      0:01 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp.log
17287 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp.ini --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp.log
17343 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto wsgi
```

When I run uwsgitop, however, it doesn't report on any of the processes running, only the master process.

```
uwsgi-1.0.3-debian - Fri Sep 30 13:21:52 2016 - req: 2488 - RPS: 11 - lq: 0 - tx: 284.0K
node: myapp - cwd: / - uid: 33 - gid: 33 - masterpid: 17279
WID    %       PID     REQ     RPS     EXC     SIG     STATUS  AVG     RSS     VSZ     TX      ReSpwn  HC      RunT    LastSpwn
```

I used to have 4 other lines, one representing each process when I viewed uwsgitop. Can anyone tell me what happened?

Also, possibly relevant information from `pip freeze` command:

```
uWSGI==2.0.13.1
uwsgitop==0.9
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Interestingly, regular 'ol top does show the process when they're consuming resources:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3445 www-data  20   0 63480 4740 3184 S  0.3  0.2  36:27.50 nginx
17666 www-data  20   0  209m  21m 9456 S  0.3  1.1   0:03.25 uwsgi
17755 www-data  20   0  208m  21m 9456 S  0.3  1.1   0:02.07 uwsgi
17808 www-data  20   0  208m  21m 9456 S  0.3  1.1   0:00.22 uwsgi
```